# Trouble running program after successful install

Tags: software-installation, find

New overwhelmed ubuntu user here, but so happy to be finally doing this. I have learned so much so far.

I just installed a package for a program called virtual moon atlas 6.0. It consists of three .tgz files; One for 386 processor, one for x86, and one for the data, and a .sh file. I ran the .sh file.

It installed, and the script ended with a output line saying that said in order to run the program run this following command. 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/virtual_moon/lib && ~/virtual_moon/bin/atlun

When I run this it says 
/home/josh/virtual_moon/bin/atlun: No such file or directory

Thinking I was some sort of genius and I decided to the run the following line of code with two vertical bars instead of two ampersands for basically no good reason.
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/virtual_moon/lib || ~/virtual_moon/bin/atlun

It ran without an error code, but I don't think it matters because I can't figure out how to launch the program or even find the program name to launch it from the command line by using the find command.
What should I do?

Thanks for any help you offer. I am so happy to join this community finally.

Comment: Welcome to [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com)!!!, did you try add `LD_RUN_PATH=/your/path` and run `ldonfig ~/your/path`??

Comment: Thank you! I ran the first line you gave me and it ran without an error. I ran the second one , and it said .... Can't create temporary cache file /etc/ld.so.cache~: Permission denied

Comment: try with `sudo` and don't forget to `export` your variable environments. finally `make install` again with some `-LIBDIR` flag see `man make` on your package

Comment: How do I export my variable environments?

Comment: if you have `LD_PATH=/your/path` environments, you can add `export LD_PATH` also check it with `echo $LD_PATH`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think your problem's not about a variable environments, i tried with following :

1. Extract the .tar of VAM6 package

   `$ tar -xvf virtualmoon-6.0-linux.tar
     vmapro_install.sh
     licence
     virtualmoon-data-6.0-linux_all.tgz
     virtualmoon-6.0-linux_x86_64.tgz
     virtualmoon-6.0-linux_i386.tgz`
2. Extract the .tgz file to get the data of VAM6

   `$ mkdir -p VMA6 && tar xzvf virtualmoon-6.0-linux_x86_64.tgz -C VMA6
     bin/
     bin/atlun
     bin/weblun
     bin/datlun
     bin/photlun
     bin/cclun
     lib/
     lib/libvma404.so
     share/
     share/applications/
     share/applications/cclun.desktop
     share/applications/virtualmoon.desktop
     share/doc/
     share/doc/virtualmoon/
     share/doc/virtualmoon/copyright
     share/doc/virtualmoon/changelog
     share/virtualmoon/
     share/virtualmoon/language/
     share/virtualmoon/language/photlun.en.po
     share/virtualmoon/language/cclun.fr.po
     share/virtualmoon/language/datlun.fr.po
     share/virtualmoon/language/cclun.en.po
     share/virtualmoon/language/maplun.en.po
     share/virtualmoon/language/weblun.fr.po
     share/virtualmoon/language/maplun.fr.po
     share/virtualmoon/language/vmadatabase.en.po
     share/virtualmoon/language/photlun.fr.po
     share/virtualmoon/language/datlun.en.po
     share/virtualmoon/language/weblun.en.po
     share/virtualmoon/language/vmadatabase.fr.po
     share/virtualmoon/data/
     share/virtualmoon/data/country.tab
     share/virtualmoon/data/retic.cur
     share/pixmaps/
     share/pixmaps/cclun.xpm
     share/pixmaps/virtualmoon.xpm`
3. Install it using `.sh` script

   `$ sudo ./vmapro_install.sh
     Virtual Moon Atlas
     You can use this script without parameter for the initial installation 
     of virtualmoon-6.0 or give the name of the additional file to install: sudo ./vmapro_install.sh PictureApollo.tgz
     Installing /home/praz/Downloads/virtualmoon-6.0-linux_x86_64.tgz
     Select installation directory [/usr/local] :/usr/local
     Now installing Virtual Moon Atlas to /usr/local
     Are you sure? [y,n] :y
     Installing /home/praz/Downloads/virtualmoon-data-6.0-linux_all.tgz
       libvma404.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/local/lib/libvma404.so
     Installation successful
     Then run Virtual Moon Atlas with the following command:
     /usr/local/bin/atlun
     Or the Command Center with the following command:
     /usr/local/bin/cclun`
4. I choose to installation directory on `/usr/local`, finally open your VAM6 using :

   `$ /usr/local/bin/atlun
     Init OpenGL
     Check Acceleration
     Check texture size
     Texture max: 16384
     Check Bumpmap
     Driver: INTEL OPEN SOURCE TECHNOLOGY CENTER MESA DRI INTEL(R) BAY TRAIL
     GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3 OK
     GL_ARB_fragment_program OK
     SetBumpMethod
     Check MultiTexture
     InitLabel
     InitSprite
     Init OpenGL OK`

**The VAM6 package will appears daemon like**

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Haha. That should have been straightforward. I should have unpacked the .tgz file before running the .sh. I think I'll try to delete everything and try again. Thanks!

Comment: One more question however. I am going to use apt-get --purge, but how can I know what the package name is to use with this command?

Comment: @josh you can purge the package using `sudo apt-get purge <your_package>` or `sudo apt-get remove <your_package>`

Comment: @josh yo're welcome! if my answer section can solved your issue, try to accept it with green checked of my answer!!

Comment: I just checked it green. You wouldn't happen to know what the package name is for virtual moon do you? I can't find it using apt-cache.

Comment: the Ubuntu Repository don't have VirtualMoon package on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net) or on [Ubuntu Packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com), only as source code archive